# WSGI : Unable to set & retrieve a cookie because on first pass the cookie does not exist to be retrieved.

Tags: python, python-2.7, mod-wsgi, wsgi

The problem is.. this line:

```
 x = cookie['r'].value
```

it wants to get the cookie with the name "r" but it can't because it has not been set yet.

for it to be set it has to not cause the script to error. so perhaps it can get the cookie on the second reload.  but it is refusing to do that.

```
import Cookie
cookie = Cookie.SimpleCookie()

def application(environ, start_response):

    cookie.load(environ['HTTP_COOKIE'])

    t = 'r=rrrr'

    headers = [('Set-Cookie', t),('Content-type', 'text/plain')]

    start_response('200 OK', headers)
    x = cookie['r'].value

    yield str(x)
```

basically i need to tell

```
  x = cookie['r'].value
```

to not cause any trouble even if it can not get the cookie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 x = cookie.get('r') and cookie['r'].value
```

Haven't actually tried it (don't have WSGI handy), but that is the standard pattern for dictionary-like object.

**For Python pups:** `get` on a dictionary returns `None` if the key doesn't exist.  `and` "short-circuits" by returning the first value if it is "falsy", which `None` (like 0 and empty string and empty list) is, and the second value if the first value is "truthy".

So if there is no cookie named "r", `cookie.get('r')` returns `None`, and the process stops there, and `x` is assigned the value `None`.  If there is such a cookie, then `cookie.get('r')` return it.  Therefore, `cookie['r'].value` is evaluated and `x` is assigned the results.

Comment: we are asking if it can be satisfied even if it does not find something.

Comment: `x` will be set to None if there is no cookie named "r".  Is that not what you wanted?

Comment: You might want to read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) to understand why it works.